# How to pass scope variable through ng-click function?

Tags: angularjs

Here when i click on cartDetails the dynamic scope variable x.SmId value need to be passed to the bellow function and in alert box need to display the parameter .How can we do this one in angular js?

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="x in names">
       <div ng-click="cartDetails('{{x.SmId}}')">
        <div>{{x.name}}</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

<script>
 angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.search = function(param) {

      $http.get('AngularJs-Response.jsp?mid='+param).success(function(response) {
        $scope.names = response;        
      });

  };
  $scope.cartDetails = function(smid) {
      alert(smid);
      };
}]);
</script>
```

Comment: `..ng-click="cartDetails(x.SmId)">`

Answer (score 9):

Use simple:-

```
 ng-click="cartDetails(x.SmId)"
```

Comment: How to pass single variable that is declared in controller without using x. ?

Comment: why don't you validate as answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use:

```
ng-click="cartDetails(x.SmId)"
```

but it simply `x.SmId` as string, its not replaced by value. After reading few more articles, I found a solution like below:

```
<div ng-click="cartDetails('{{x.SmId}}')">
```

Its a working solution in AngularJS v1.3.9

Comment: And if you want the `x.SmId` as a boolean? What should we do? Because `'false'` equals `true`. Any ideas?